# insert checkbox with two value codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox, where-clause

in my view:

```
<form  method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Data/Penilaian/Selected">
  <table class="table datatable-responsive" id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th><button class="btn btn-info">Submit</button></th>
      <th>No</th>
       <th>Kendaraan</th>
       <th>Plat Nomor</th>
      <th>Total</th>  
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
      $no=1; 
      if(!empty($getsifat)) {
        foreach ($getsifat as $kr_key => $kendaraan) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td>
          <?php foreach ($kendaraan['sub']['count'] as $data)     { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="id_kendaraan[]" value="<?php echo $kendaraan['id_kendaraan'] ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="total[]" value="<?php echo $data['total'] ?>" > //this my problem
          <?php } ?>
          </td>
          <td><?php echo $no ?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $kendaraan['nama'] ?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $kendaraan['platno'] ?></td>
          <?php
          foreach ($kendaraan['sub']['count'] as $data)     { ?>
          <!-- <input type="hidden" name="total[]" value="<?php echo $data['total'] ?>"> -->
          <td><?php echo $data['total'] ?></td>
          <?php } ?>
        </tr> 
    <?php 
      $no++; 
        }
      } 
    ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </form>
```

in view i want to insert `$id_kendaraan` and `$total` value

this my controller:

```
 function Selected(){
          $id_kendaraan = $this->input->post('id_kendaraan');
          $total = $this->input->post('total');
          $data = array();
          for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $id_kendaraan ); $i++ ) {
            $data = array(
            'id_kendaraan' =>  $id_kendaraan[$i],
            'total' =>  $total[$i]
            );
            $this->PenilaianModel->TambahSelected($id_kendaraan, $data);
            }
          redirect('Data/Penilaian', 'refresh');
        }
```

my model:

```
function TambahSelected($id_kendaraan, $data)
    {
    $this->db->where('id_kendaraan', $id_kendaraan);
    $this->db->insert('tb_ranking', $data);
    }
```

i want to insert $id_kendaraan and $total to my db
but if i try this code:
examle in view:

```
id kendaraan value = 1, total value = 20
id kendaraan value = 2, total value = 35
id kendaraan value = 3, total value = 44
```

if i checked $id_kendaraan 2 and press submit, in my databases data $id_kendaraan value = 2, $total value = 20, is not correct... in my db this data should be $id_kendaraan value = 2, $total value = 35

and if i try checked $id_kendaraan 3 and press submit, in my databases data $id_kendaraan value = 3, $total value = 20, is not correct... in my db this data should be $id_kendaraan value = 3, $total value = 44

and if i try checked $id_kendaraan 2,3 and press submit, in my databases data $id_kendaraan value = 2, $total value = 20 and $id_kendaraan value = 3, total value = 35, is not correct... in my db this data should be $id_kendaraan value = 2, $total value = 35 and $id_kendaraan value = 3, $total value = 44

thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because hidden array will send all the data but your check box will post only selected array values. So key mismatch will happen in your server side code. To solve this you need to serve array keys uniquely.

Rearrange your front end code as like follows.

```
<?php 
  $no=1; 
  if(!empty($getsifat)) {
    $inputid = 0;
    foreach ($getsifat as $kr_key => $kendaraan) { 
      $attch1 = $attch2 = "";
      foreach ($kendaraan['sub']['count'] as $data){
        $attch1 .= '<input type="checkbox" name="id_kendaraan['.$inputid.']" value="'.$kendaraan['id_kendaraan'].'">';
        $attch1 .= '<input type="hidden" name="total['.$inputid.']" value="'.$data['total'].'" >';

        $attch2 .= '<td>'.$data['total'].'</td>';
        $inputid++;
      }
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $attch1 ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $no ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $kendaraan['nama'] ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $kendaraan['platno'] ?></td>
      <?php echo $attch2 ?>
    </tr> 
<?php 
  $no++; 
    }
  } 
?>
```

Rewrite controller as like

```
 public function Selected(){
    $id_kendaraan = $this->input->post('id_kendaraan');
    $total = $this->input->post('total');
    $data = array();
    foreach ($id_kendaraan as $key => $value) {
        $data = array(
        'id_kendaraan' =>  $value,
        'total' =>  $total[$key]
        );
        $this->PenilaianModel->TambahSelected($id_kendaraan, $data);
    }          
    redirect('Data/Penilaian', 'refresh');
  }
```

**NOTE :**

> 1. You were looping same loop twice. I made it as one.
> 2. in line  You are printing  inside loop. I guess it will come outside loop.
> 3. no need of line `$this->db->where('id_kendaraan', $id_kendaraan)` in insert context.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
$this->db->where('id_kendaraan', $id_kendaraan);
```

To update values , you should use `where`.

Comment: still incompatible, $id_kendaraan not Compatible with $total